# Remoting into Server to get Orcale.DataAccess.dll

Tags: c#, winforms, dll, remoting, .net-remoting

I am remoting into a server which has the Orcale.DataAccess.dll in the GAC. However when I call a function in the .dll I get the following exception:

`'Could not load file or assembly 'Orcale.DataAccess, Version=2.112.2.0, Culture=netural, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified'`

It is a `Windows Server 2003 32 bit` and I am remoting from a XP SP3 32bit client.

Any help will be appreciated ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the XP SP3 32bit machine, do you have the oracle client version (Version=2.112.2.0) running on the win 2003 server?

If no, try this:
1. Copy the oracle dll from 2003 server to project library.
2. Rebuild project and try again.

Comment: I have Orcale 10.2 on both but I have Orcale Data Provider .net 10.1.0.4.0 on the XP Client and 10.2.0.1.0 on the server, but does it matter what is on the client as it remotes into the server and does not use the client GAC ?

Comment: I experienced something similar recently, where the oracle provider on my development machine was different from that in production. I simply copied the oracle.DataAccess.dll on production to my visual studio (IDE for development) and rebuild the solution. This solved the problem

Comment: I replaced the server .dll with the client one and I get a different error message, however I only get this error message as the .dll is x64 while the project is trageting x86, I have got a solution for this tho